# Errors when exporting query from MS Access to Excel 2007 using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, export-to-excel

I am trying to use

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,, _
        "QueryName", "Path\FileName.xlsm", True
```

I have also tried

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        "QueryName", "Path\FileName.xlsm", True
```

to export data from MSAccess Database to Excel file(.xlsm). Everything is working fine but after the export the data when i open the excel file i get the below error. Please provide me some examples.

[image: Excel found unreadable content, do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?]

Comment: What happens when you click YES?

Comment: If i click yes , I can see output in the file, but i cannot make any changes to it  or run the macros automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"wont run the macros automatically"**

I know its probably a deal breaker but you might need users to go into Excel > Options and set the Trust required for macros to run.

**"i cannot make any changes to it"**

Thats probably because MS Access still has a lock on the xls file it produced, if you close MS Access then open a exported spreadsheet is it still Read-Only (if so then right click on the xls > Properties and uncheck ReadOnly).

> I did some research and wished to share my findings. - each one of
>   these threads does have a successful outcome with troubleshooting
>   discussed. Unless you post the accdb and the xls it will be hard for
>   us to help you find the specific issue, its going to be a case of
>   trial and error.

[Error message when you try to open a workbook in Excel 2007: Excel found unreadable content in Book_Name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929766)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/excel/thread/f8abedda-619e-4f9d-97a5-fba2fcacd8c2

http://help.lockergnome.com/office/Excel-found-unreadable-content--ftopict945084.html

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=562612

Comment: @Jeremy....I appreciate your research, thank you for your valuable comments/answers

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the macro in a seperate Personal.xls workbook or addin on the machine opening the exported workbook. Does the macro have to be in the exported workbook?

You could check for Workbook Open in an Application wide event

Comment: @Sico... That cannot be done because the macro is there for a purpose in that workbook, and its nt a small workbook to convert that.In the question i mentioned only query, but the vba code in the MSAccess database has many queries which returns data to different tabs in the excel work book and the executes the macro in the excel work book.

Comment: found this. does it answer your question http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=425958